# How to code a linear combination in Gurobi

Tags: mathematical-optimization, gurobi

I have found the following example as on how to code the constraint "the sum over all a_{i,j}*x_{i,j} with j element of J is <=5 for all i in I". (sorry, I don't know how to properly write this in code, here is a first try):

```
\sum{a_{i,j}*x_{i,j}} <= 5
```

in Gurobi python:

```
m.addConstr(x.prod(a,i,'*') <=5 for i in I)
```

I would really appreciate if someone could explain this expression to me!

Here is what I understand: 
m is usually used as a variable to store the model, in a program we would start with `m = Model()` to create an empty model. 
We add one constraint with `addConstr()` and x must have been introduced as a variable. the `x.prod()` method creates a linear combination of its parameters. However, I don't know how to interpret the three parameters `a, i, '*'`
i is part of the for loop, it starts with 1 and then gets incremented by one until the last element of I is reached. '*' is used as a wildcard and will address just any element. But what does this combination of `a, i, '*'` tell me?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question properly without knowing what `a` is. Could you provide the whole example? Furthermore I think it should be `m.addConstrs` instead of `m.addConstr`.

Comment: [here](http://www.gurobi.com/pdfs/user-events/2017-frankfurt/Modeling-1.pdf) is a link of the presentation I am reading. The example I am talking about is on slide 27 (implicit)

Answer (score 0):

a is a parameter and has two index i,j. ' * ' means for all j.  Using ' * ', you don't need "for loop" for j like, "for loop" for i. You can see that in explicit form at the slayt which has two "for loop".